# Get dynamic web pages using Java

Tags: java, javascript, browser

I want to write a program to automatically harvest information by login to a website and then download some pages. I use HttpURLConnection and I manage session with cookies. However it looks like that some parts of the page, like tables, are generated dynamically using javascript.

Do I have to execute javascript code inside my java program?

Comment: "Yes". Although I suspect there are better approaches, such as using a library that uses embedded Webkit or Gecko cores to fetch pages - it's more than just "running" JavaScript; the JavaScript must execute against a particular DOM/environment to be of use to mimic a web-page rendering.

Comment: So to simply retrieve data inside a table generated dynamically should I use Webkit or Gecko? Is there a way to interact through Chrome without actually open a Chrome window etc?

Comment: Well, not "require" - but most libraries I've seen that have JavaScript applied to a DOM (e.g. advanced HTML to PDF converters) use one of the existing web-browser "cores" (Chrome is a variant of Webkit) - so they effectively use a non-UI version of Chrome/IE/FF underneath. These libraries use the rendering/JavaScript engines in a "headless" mode.